# How do I wrap this jquery plugin's callback function with RxJS Observables/Subjects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to use https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete with Websockets and RxJS.

Normally, the `lookup` AJAX function looks like this:

```
lookup: await (query, done) => {
    // make ajax call
    const response = await fetch(// pass query str here);
    const respJson = await response.json();
    done(respJson);
}
```

The `query` is the string that is being entered, and `done` is the callback function that we pass the results to.

I want to wrap this functionality in RxJS observables or subjects, so I can do things like debouncing. Here's what I have so far:

```
const webSocketSubject = webSocket(`/ws/typeahead/`);
const subject = new Subject();

webSocketSubject.subscribe(console.log)

const debouncedSubject = subject.pipe(
    debounceTime(200)
);
debouncedSubject.subscribe((x) => {
    webSocketSubject.next({
        'payload': {
            'query': x,
        },
    });
    console.log(x);
});


 $('#id_my_input_field').autocomplete({
     lookup: (query, done) => {
         debouncedSubject.next(query);
     }
 });
```

I have tested this code, and I can see that it does send websocket messages to the server, I can see responses.

How do I pass the results from the websocket Subject to the `done` callback?

Comment: Take a look at rxjs [`bindCallback`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/bindCallback)

Comment: @Kos I'm not understanding how to use `bindCallback` in this case. Could you provide an example that incorporates the code in my question?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, bindCallback wont help indeed. Yet, using RxJS in this `lookup` method going to look weird, imho. As far as I see it, inside of the `lookup` you'll have to subscribe `done` callback to your result stream. So, before going that road... wont jQuery `debounce` method fit your needs?

Comment: Does jquery have its own `debounce` method? Or are you talking about a jquery plugin?

Comment: I ask because I was unable to find a built-in jquery `debounce` method.

Comment: Doh, I thought it was native to `jQuery`, but it seems to be a [plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/). Yet `debounce` is in no way bound to jQuery and could be found in [many](https://github.com/component/debounce) different [libraries](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce)

Comment: Cool, I went with the lodash `throttle` method, which was more inline with what I was actually looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Np! Sorry for misleading you on the way :)